# Wireless or Wired Apple keyboard for programming?

Tags: keyboard, wifi

Why one or the other?

I don't use the numpad nor much of the functional keys (delete, insert, etc.).

The latency with the wireless worries.

What are your experiences?

Comment: Don't sweat wired or wireless. Use whatever you're comfortable working with for very long stretches of time. In my case that will *never* be a "chiclet" type keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the wired version primarily because it has a 10-key pad, the dedicated page up/down and home/end keys, and the arrow keys aren't so tiny.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Wireless Apple Keyboard and there isn't any noticeable lag when using it. Unless you program *really really* quickly, I don't see a problem with using the wireless keyboard.

The only problem with the keyboard is when it is far away from the Mac - the Bluetooth signal could weaken and slow down the process.

Comment: I've always had fast response up to 30 feet away and never seen slowness. It seems to drop the connection entirely before lag due to retransmissions gets bad or even noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend the wireless keyboard (keeping any old USB one around only for maintenance boots/backup).

My dream setup is a [Twelve South MagicWand](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H3443ZM/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) connecting a Magic trackpad with the bluetooth keyboard. Gestures are so powerful in Xcode and for swiping windows around. Lion is just going to make that input method better. I expect it will be a one year period of weaning myself from my mouse. For now it's still always on my desk and ready, but I'm starting to use it less as I get more proficient on the trackpad.

More info on the [MagicWand is here](http://twelvesouth.com/products/magicwand/). As I commented below on another answer for wireless, I've never seen lag as the device disconnects with a nice animation on the mac screen if it's not a reliable and fast connection.

Comment: cool, i've never seen those before.

Answer (score 0):

I use the wired keyboard primarily because it has two easy access USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen slowness on the Wireless of any sort, latency is not an issue. Period.

On the other hand, key feel *is* an issue. The key mechanisms are different between Wired and Wireless; its harder to press the keys on the Wireless and it has a mushy feel.

I tried one because I never used the numeric keypad (and I am a programmer) and was fine with the re-located cursor keys. The feel was so poor that my typo rate *soared*. Even a few hours of trying it prompted me to return it.

I do want to try the older Compact Wired version. If it uses the say keys as the current wired, I'll switch.